# Regular Expression Not Matching Escaped Parenthesis

Tags: regex, word-boundary

I have a very simple regular expression that will not match an escaped parenthesis as I am expecting (Live example: https://regex101.com/r/RRupbC/1/).

The Regular Expression:

```
/\b(?:Test1 \(VI|Test2 \(VI\))\b/gi
```

Sample Input:

```
Test1 (VI      <- Match
Test2 (VI)     <- No Match
```

I would expect the regular expression to match on the second input as it satisfies the second condition of Test2 (VI). It seems to not acknowledge the closing parenthesis as a valid match.

Why is this logic incorrect, and how can I modify the expression to successfully match my second input example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second string doesn't match because of the final `\b`. In particular, the effective regex you're executing is

```
\bTest2 \(VI\)\b
```

, which matches

- a word boundary
- the string `Test2 (VI)`
- another word boundary

A "word boundary" is the empty space between a word character and a non-word character or vice versa (the beginning/end of the string counts as a non-word character for this purpose).

Because `)` is a non-word character, it needs to be followed by a word character in the target string to make `)\b` match (e.g. `Test2 (VI)x` should match successfully).

A minimal solution might be to pull the `\b` into the first branch:

```
\b(?:Test1 \(VI\b|Test2 \(VI\))
```